# Why a past-inextendible causal curve can have a starting point?

Tags: general-relativity, causality

I have some doubts about the notions of future and past-inextendible causal curves.
The definitions of future and past inextendible causal curve that I have are the following:

> Let $\gamma$ be a future-directed causal curve. Then $\gamma$ has a *future
> endpoint* $p\in M$ if for every neighbourhood $O$ of $p$ there
> exists a $t_{0}$ such that  $\gamma(t)\in O\  \forall t>t_{0}$.

> Let $\gamma$ be a past-directed causal curve. Then $\gamma$ has a *past
> endpoint* $p\in M$ if for every neighbourhood $O$ of $p$ there
> exists a $t_{0}$ such that  $\gamma(t)\in O\  \forall t<t_{0}$.

Intuitively, in the Minkowski spacetime $\mathcal{M}$, I understand a past-directed causal curve as a causal curve $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$ that goes down in a Minkowski diagram when the parameter $\lambda$ in $\gamma(\lambda)$ increases (with respect to an inertial observer). That is, the coordinate $t$ of $\gamma(\lambda_1)$ is less than the coordinate $t$ of $\gamma(\lambda_2)$ when $\lambda_1<\lambda_2$.

In the same way, I understand a future-directed causal curve as a causal curve $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$ that goes up in a Minkowski diagram when the parameter $\lambda$ in $\gamma(\lambda)$ increases (with respect to an inertial observer).

If I use this understanding, a series of doubts arise:

Why a past-inextendible causal curve can have a starting point?

Is it possible to define the notion of *past-starting point* for future directed causal curves?

Some people say that, when in a future-directed causal curve you eliminate a point, then the portion of the curve before such a point becomes an future-inextendible causal curve, but I don't understand why. According to me, when you eliminate such a point, that point becomes a future-endpoint of the portion of the curve before it, so the curve is actually extendible

If you can put some figures in your answer, that will help me a lot.

Comment: The definitions you provided are of endpoints, not exactly of future/past-inextendible causal curves, so I'm not fully sure of which definition you're using. If I recall correctly, a future-inextendible causal curve is a future-directed causal curve without a future endpoint, but this definition makes your question "Why a past-inextendible causal curve can have a starting point?" not make sense to me

Comment: It would also be helpful to mention the source of the definitions you're providing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why a past-inextendible causal curve can have a starting point?

It can have a starting point as long as that starting point is located to the future of the causal curve. Hence, a "past-inextendible causal curve starting at $p$" is everywhere in the causal past of $p$.

> Is it possible to define the notion of past-starting point for future directed causal curves?

You can consider any future-directed causal curve as a past-directed causal curve by reversing the parameterization (given $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathcal{M}$ future directed, define $\delta \colon [-b,-a] \to \mathcal{M}$, by $\delta(\lambda) = \gamma(-\lambda)$). You can then use the usual definition for past-directed curves. Alternatively,

> Let $\gamma$ be a future-directed causal curve. Then $\gamma$ has a starting point $p \in \mathcal{M}$ if for every neighbourhood $O$ of $p$ there exists a $t_0$ such that $\gamma(t) \in O, \forall t > t_0$.

> Some people say that, when in a future-directed causal curve you eliminate a point, then the portion of the curve before such a point becomes an future-inextendible causal curve, but I don't understand why. According to me, when you eliminate such a point, that point becomes a future-endpoint of the portion of the curve before it, so the curve is actually extendible

Suppose $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{M}$ is a future-inextendible causal curve. Pick $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, define $p = \gamma(t_0)$ and consider the spacetime $\mathcal{M} \setminus \lbrace p\rbrace$. Then the curve $\delta: (-\infty,t_0) \to \mathcal{M} \setminus \lbrace p\rbrace$ defined by $\delta(\lambda) = \gamma(\lambda)$ is future-inextendible. The reason is that you can't make the curve go past the point $p$, since it is not in the spacetime anymore. It is a "hole" in spacetime. Rigorously, it is not an endpoint of $\delta$ because the only candidate to an endpoint for $\delta$ is $p$ (since $\gamma$ was inextendible). However, $p$ can't be an endpoint, because it is not even in the spacetime. In the definition

> Let $\gamma$ be a future-directed causal curve. Then $\gamma$ has a future endpoint point $p \in \mathcal{M}$ if for every neighbourhood $O$ of $p$ there exists a $t_0$ such that $\gamma(t) \in O, \forall t < t_0$,

you don't have any valid $t_0$ (since we excluded $t_0$ from the domain of $\delta$, and if we didn't we'd not have a function, since $\delta$ would run into something that is not in spacetime). Due to this, $\delta$ is inextendible (and $\mathcal{M} \setminus \lbrace p\rbrace$ is singular, $p$ being what we'd call the singularity).

Comment: You say that a past inextendible causal curve doesn't have a starting point, however in the Barrett O'Neil's book "Semi-riemannian geometry" there are many statements where he says: Let $\alpha$ be a past inextendible causal curve starting at p...

Comment: I think the mistake is in the definition of past-endpoint. Instead of $\forall~t<t_0$, the correct is $\forall~t>t_0$

Comment: @ThomasBelichick Adding O'Neil's statement helped me understand what was going on. Please take a look at the edited version of the answer (I only changed the first bit, about the starting point)